# Scala: take stream "while increasing"

Tags: scala, collections

I want to traverse a sequence:

```
val data = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8)
```

My goal is to build a new sequence but only take data up to the point where the their values stop increasing. So the desired output would be `Seq(1,2,3,4,5)` in this case.

I think the solution lies in using `takeWhile` and `sliding` (to access the next value), but I cannot figure out how to combine them.

Comment: You recognise it needs `takeWhile` and `sliding`. If you enter that into the search box at top right, this is one of the first hits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872049/scala-increasing-prefix-of-a-sequence/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky, but working:

```
data
  .view
  .scanLeft(Option.empty[Int]) {
    case (None, item) => Option(item)
    case (Some(prev), item) => Option(item).filter(cur => cur > prev)
  }
  .tail
  .takeWhile(_.isDefined)
  .flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
val strictIncreasingData = 
(Seq(Int.MinValue)++data).sliding(2).takeWhile{case Seq(current,next) => next>current}.map{case Seq(current,next) => next}.toSeq
```

the trick is to convert the `Iterator` (from `sliding`) back to a sequence. The prepending of `Int.MinValue` makes sure no element are swallowed. This solution does not work for an empty collection

Comment: Swallows last correct item

Comment: @Nyavro Thank, I corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Zip with tail**

```
data zip data.tail takeWhile { case (a, b) => a < b } map (_._1) toSeq
```

Comment: Swallows last correct item

Answer (score 0):

There are answers outside the collections API ;)

This can be refactored to something more readable. Just to give an impression:

```
def takeWhileIncreasing(in: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = {
  @tailrec def internal(in: Seq[Int], out: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = {
    in match {
      case prev +: (tail @ (next +: _)) if next > prev =>
        internal(tail, prev +: out)
      case prev +: (tail @ (next +: _)) if next <= prev =>
        prev +: out
      case _ =>
        out
    }
  }

  internal(in, Seq.empty).reverse
}
```

Comment: "This can be refactored to something more readable".  I should hope so! :-P